# How to disappear the agent in ANYLOGIC

Tags: process, simulation, anylogic

I'm using Anylogic to simulate a supply chain, but I have a question.

I'm going to try explain my process:

1. The material comes in a truck and and after pass to storage
2. After do an process pinking material
3. The material shipment

In the step 3, my box (is the object with I simulate the material) is moving for a forklift to inside the truck, but when the trucks out, the box doesn't disappear.

I tried some ideas but it isn't disappearing.

I used a block release for the agent box but doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this when the box enters the truck, where boxShape is the image you use to represent your box:

```
boxAgent.boxShape.setVisible(false)
```

another way is to use a pickup block for the truck grabbing all the boxes

another way is to move the box to a box population inside the truck agent in which the image of the box is not visible on upper agent

and many many many more ways

Comment: Thank you I tried and mark that box cannot be resolved. I put the code in the visible of truck, I dont know if I did correct

Comment: you can also destroy the agent doing agent.deleteSelf();

Comment: I can´t solve yet. But I´m trying.